# Is ul#Content not the same as #Content ul?

Tags: css

I'm debugging my css code as my ul are not coming out with indents and bullets as expected.

I've got a lot of UL's in my css but I've written them in various ways. I've tried to make them uniform, i.e. ul after the div name, but they behave differently. Can someone help me understand the difference as I want to write these statements in one uniform way.

```
ul#Content li {// do something}

#Content ul li {// do something}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ul#content li` matches any li contained in a `ul` which has `id="content"`, example:

```
<ul id="content">
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

`#content ul li` matches any `li` contained in a `ul`, contained in another element which has `id="content"`. Example:

```
<div id="content>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

They note diffeerent things:

```
ul#Content li {// do something}
```

all `li` elements inside elements of type `ul` with the `ul` having the id 'Content'

```
#Content ul li {// do something}
```

all `li` elements inside an `ul` element that is inside some container with id 'Content'

So the question is: is 'Content' the id if the `ul` or of its container ?